# Producer callback in Spring Cloud Stream with reactor core publisher

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-producer-api

I have written a spring cloud stream application where producers are publishing messages to the designated kafka topics. My query is how can I add a producer callback to receive ack/confirmation that the message has been successfully published on the topic? Like how we do in spring kafka `producer.send(record, new callback { ... })` (maintaining async producer). Below is my code:

```java
private final Sinks.Many<Message<?>> responseProcessor = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<?>>> event() {
        return responseProcessor::asFlux;
    }    

public Message<?> publishEvent(String status) {
  try {
      String key = ...;
      response = MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
                  .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, key)
                  .build();
      responseProcessor.tryEmitNext(response);
  }
```

How can I make sure that **tryEmitNext** has successfully written to the topic?

Is implementing **ProducerListener** a solution and possible? Couldn't find a concrete solution/documentation in Spring Cloud Stream

**UPDATE**

I have implemented below now, seems to work as expected

```
@Component
public class MyProducerListener<K, V> implements ProducerListener<K, V> {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
        // Do nothing on onSuccess
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception exception) {
        log.error("Producer exception occurred while publishing message : {}, exception : {}", producerRecord, exception);
    }

}

 @Bean
    ProducerMessageHandlerCustomizer<KafkaProducerMessageHandler<?, ?>> customizer(MyProducerListener pl) {
        return (handler, destinationName) -> handler.getKafkaTemplate().setProducerListener(pl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Kafka Producer Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-producer-properties).

> **recordMetadataChannel**

> The bean name of a `MessageChannel` to which successful send results should be sent; the bean must exist in the application context. The message sent to the channel is the sent message (after conversion, if any) with an additional header `KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA`. The header contains a `RecordMetadata` object provided by the Kafka client; it includes the partition and offset where the record was written in the topic.

> ResultMetadata meta = sendResultMsg.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.RECORD_METADATA, RecordMetadata.class)

> Failed sends go the producer error channel (if configured); see Error Channels. Default: null

You can add a `@ServiceActivator` to consume from this channel asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I updated question with the implementation that I have done. Would there be any issue with this approach? I don't think so. I don't want to introduce error channels, don't have this requirement & support. Just logging the unpublished message would suffice !

Comment: Yes; that's a valid solution.